# Counting all possible paths between 2 nodes in directed graph using adjacency list (int[][])

Tags: java, graph

I'm trying to count all paths between 2 nodes in a directed graph. The graph may be cyclic however, I want to avoid return back to the source node -- thus avoiding infinite loops. The adjacency lists are defined as follows:

```
adjlist = {{ 1, 2 },{ 0, 3 },{ 0, 3 },{ 1, 2 },}
```

meaning that node 0 (first in list) can connect to nodes 1 and 2, node 1 can connect to nodes 0 and 3, node 2 can connect to nodes 0 and 3, and node 3 can connect to nodes 1 and 2.

I have tried this:

```
 public int numPaths(int[][] adjlist, int src, int dst) {
 // TODO
 int paths = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i < adjlist[src].length; i++) {
     boolean[] visited = new boolean[adjlist.length];
     visited[src] = true;
     DFS2(adjlist, adjlist[src][i], dst, paths, visited);
 }
 return paths;
}

 public static void DFS2(int[][] adjlist, int src, int dst, int paths, boolean[] visited) {
 visited[src] = true;
 if (src == dst) {
     paths++;
 }
 else {
     for (int i = 0; i < adjlist[src].length; i++) {
         if (visited[i] == false) {
             DFS2(adjlist, adjlist[src][i], dst, paths, visited);
         }
     }
 }
```

}

I am using DFS however im getting the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Meaning I'm getting an infinite recursion.
Any help would be great, thanks.